# ant fresh_install error/build failed 4 seconds

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, dspace

Guys
I am installing Dspace 6.2 on Windows 10, and I have meet wiith error below while I am running "ant fresh_install".Here is the configuration I am using:
 dspace-6.2-src-release, jdk1.8.0_171, apache-tomcat-8.5.30,apache-maven-3.3.3,postgresql "pgAdmin 4 v1.6 released".

This is the error:

C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer>ant fresh_install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="OracleJava7Fix"
Buildfile: C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml

init_installation:

prepare_configs:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 158 files to C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 16 files to C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp

init_configs:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\dspace\config
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp

test_database:
     [java] 2018-04-26 11:47:02,427 WARN  org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder @ Internal error
     [java] org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source local.cfg
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:259)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:238)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$FileConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1455)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$ConfigurationBeanFactory.createBean(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1321)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:390)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:412)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:426)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.createConfigurationAt(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:855)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.initCombinedConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:719)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:622)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:587)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.loadInitialConfig(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:494)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:87)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:148)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:49)
     [java] 2018-04-26 11:47:04,170 WARN  org.dspace.services.email.EmailServiceImpl @ Couldn't get an email session from environment:  Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
     [java] 2018-04-26 11:47:04,414 ERROR org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils @ Unable to setup Flyway against DSpace database
     [java] java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace")
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
     [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.setupFlyway(DatabaseUtils.java:473)
     [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:98)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]
     [java] Error running 'test':
     [java]  - java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace")
     [java]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java] Please see the DSpace documentation for assistance.
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:229)
     [java] java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace")
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:81)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
     [java] Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
     [java]
     [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:446)
     [java]     at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:105)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:220)      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:55)
     [java]
     [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:219)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:229)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:81)
     [java] Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2304)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:446)        ... 10 more
     [java]
     [java]
     [java]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:220)
     [java] Attempting to connect to database   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:55)
     [java]
     [java] 2018-04-26 11:47:04,451 WARN  org.dspace.services.sessions.SessionRequestServiceImpl @ Request interceptor (org.dspace.services.events.SystemEventService$EventRequestInterceptor@359cd110) failed to execute on end (request-297-1524754024364): null
     [java]     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:219)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
     [java]     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2304)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
     [java]     ... 9 more
     [java] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="OracleJava7Fix"

BUILD FAILED
C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml:792: Java returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds

C:\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace-6.2-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer>

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please format your post to make it more readable (Bold, italic, list , code indentation etc) 
Please check [FAQs on **Asking**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and make it  [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(**MCVE**)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"

The install script could not make a connection to the database because the credentials it used were not correct.  The probable cause of this is earlier in the session:

org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source local.cfg

The correct database credentials (and much else) should be found in 'local.cfg', but the installer could not find that file.  Without it, the default database user 'dspace' and password 'dspace' from config/dspace.cfg would be used.  You need to find out why 'local.cfg' cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks, Mark I have created local.cfg file and a new password for my database then I run "ant fresh_install ", now it works thank you very much...